# npm country-state-city module not accepting value passed from ion-select

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm

I am creating a registration form which a user should select State and City from dropdowns (when the state is selected, the state ID is passed to the function that retrieves an array of cities in the state). To achieve this i am using the npm's **country-state-city** module.

The problem comes in that when the State is selected, as much as the correct ID value is passed in the correct format (string), an empty array of Cities is returned (i use console.log to display selected value to confirm the correct value is passed) but if I add the state ID directly to a variable, the cities are returned.

My interface script is:

```
                <ion-header>
                  <ion-toolbar>
                    <ion-title></ion-title>
                  </ion-toolbar>
                </ion-header>

                <ion-content>
                        <ion-item *ngIf='displayState'>
                            <ion-list>
                                <ion-item>
                                    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="stateID"
                              placeholder="Region/State" (ionChange)="onStateSelect($event)">
                                        <ion-select-option 
                                           *ngFor="let state of this.stateInfo"  
                                             value=" {{ state['id'] }}"> 
                                              {{ state['name'] }} </ion-select-option>
                                    </ion-select>                                   
                                </ion-item>
                            </ion-list>                     
                        </ion-item>
                        
                        <ion-item *ngIf='displayCity'>
                            <ion-list>
                                <ion-item>
                                    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="cityID">
                                        <ion-select-option 
                                             *ngFor="let city of this.cityInfo"
                                              value=" {{ city['id'] }} ">{{ city['name']}} 
                                              </ion-select-option>
                                    </ion-select>                                   
                                </ion-item>
                            </ion-list>                     
                        </ion-item>     
                </ion-content>
```

My backend is:

```
                import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
                import csc from 'country-state-city';

                @Component({
                  selector: 'app-country',
                  templateUrl: './country.page.html',
                  styleUrls: ['./country.page.scss'],
                })
                export class CountryPage implements OnInit {

                    public countrycode = "IE";
                    public libCountryCodeID = '';
                    public stateInfo = {};
                    public cityInfo = {};
                    
                    public stateID = "";
                    public cityID = "";

                    
                    public displayCity: boolean = false;
                    public displayState: boolean = true;
                    

                    constructor() {
                        //this.locationInfo(csc.getCountryByCode(this.countrycode));
                        
                    }
                    
                    ngOnInit() {
                        let loc = csc.getCountryByCode(this.countrycode);
                        console.log(loc.id);
                        
                        
                        this.libCountryCodeID = loc.id;
                        
                        this.stateInfo = csc.getStatesOfCountry(this.libCountryCodeID);
                        console.log(this.stateInfo);
                        
                    
                    }
                    
                    displayCityInfo(id)
                    {
                        console.log(this.stateID);
                        
                        //this.test = this.stateID;
                        this.cityInfo = csc.getCitiesOfState(id);
                        console.log(this.cityInfo);
                        
                        this.displayCity = true;
                    }
                    
                    onStateSelect($event)
                    {
                        
                        console.log(this.stateID);
                        
                        this.displayCityInfo(this.stateID); 
                    }

                }
```

Comment: If all the data is returned correctly but not showing, it indicates that there needs to be a notification change event which tells IONIC to reload.  Does IONIC have anything like that? Or does it do automatic change detection?  Obviously not if new data doesn't show.

Comment: Hi @JohnPeters, thanks for the response. I am not sure let me check that out and get back to you. Thanks